# Setting TP and SL on Strategy in pips

Tags: pine-script

Noob question: I have long and short conditions for a strategy I'd like to try and I want to set both my TP and SL to 40 pips, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do that since pine strategies don't seem to be too pip-friendly. I'd like my starting balance to be $1000 and each trade to use 90% of my equity balance. Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=90)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)) and strategy.position_size == 0
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28)) and strategy.position_size == 0
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    
strategy.exit("x", loss = 40, profit = 40)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression the value of loss and profit was in currency. This helps clarify that.